# MySQL after delete Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables `member_details` and `archives`. I want a `trigger` that will `insert` deleted data from `member_details` into `archives` as soon as as a particular record is deleted from the `member_details` table.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER member_details_ADEL AFTER DELETE ON member_details 
FOR EACH ROW 
insert into archives values
```

Comment: ok good so where is your code and where you got stuck ?

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `member_details_ADEL`
 AFTER DELETE ON `member_details` FOR EACH ROW
insert into `archives` values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OLD` keyword to fetch values from the deleted record.
But you have to specify column names with the `insert` statement.

**Example** :

```
delimiter //

drop trigger if exists member_details_adel //

create trigger member_details_adel 
       after delete on member_details 
       for each row 
         insert 
           into archives( col1, col2, colx ) 
         values( old.col1, old.col2, old.colx );

//

delimiter ;
```

Change and extend column names as per your table needs.

**Update 1**:

There was syntax error in your tried trigger body.
Corrected one is as follows:

```
delimiter $$ 
create trigger member_details_adel 
       after delete on member_details 
       for each row 
         insert 
           into archives (title,  name,  name of spouse,  
                          level of education,  address,  
                          phone number,  occupation,  
                          date joined,  emergency contact)
         values (old.title,  old.name, old.`name of spouse`, 
                 old.`level of education`, old.`address`, 
                 old.`phone number`, old.`occupation`, 
                 old.`date joined`, old.`emergency contact`); 
$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: this is what I wrote
USE `church`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `member_details_ADEL`
AFTER DELETE ON `member_details` FOR EACH ROW
insert into `archives` (`TITLE`,
  `NAME`,
  `NAME OF SPOUSE`,
  `LEVEL OF EDUCATION`,
  `ADDRESS`,
  `PHONE NUMBER`,
  `OCCUPATION`,
  `DATE JOINED`,
  `EMERGENCY CONTACT`)
 values (`old.TITLE`,
  `old.NAME`,
  ` old.NAME OF SPOUSE`,
  ` old.LEVEL OF EDUCATION`,
  ` old.ADDRESS`,
  ` old.PHONE NUMBER`,
  ` old.OCCUPATION`,
  ` old.DATE JOINED`,
  ` old.EMERGENCY CONTACT`);
delimiter ;

//

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it, lets say you have a table called test with the following data

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+----------------------+
| id                   |
+----------------------+
| 10                   |
| 20                   |
| 30                   |
+----------------------+
```

You have another table called test1 as no data currently

```
mysql> select * from test1 ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Now lets write a trigger so that when there is a delete on the test table the deleted record gets added to the test1 table. You need to use `after delete` trigger for this and the using `old.col` you can get the data

In this example I have only one column you can use old.col name to access any column on the table where the trigger is executing

```
delimiter //
create trigger log_delete after delete on test
for each row
begin
  insert into test1 (id) values (old.id);
end ; //
delimiter ;
```

Now lets delete a record in test table as

```
mysql> delete from test where id = 10 ;
Query OK, 1 row affected,  (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test ;
+----------------------+
| id                   |
+----------------------+
| 20                   |
| 30                   |
+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test1 ;
+----------------------+
| id                   |
+----------------------+
| 10                   |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now as you can see the deleted row has been added to the table test1.

All you need to do is to set proper table names and the column names in the above trigger along with the trigger name you want to have

```
USE church; 
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER member_details_ADEL AFTER DELETE ON member_details 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
    insert into archives 
    (TITLE, NAME, `NAME OF SPOUSE`, `LEVEL OF EDUCATION`, ADDRESS, `PHONE NUMBER`, OCCUPATION, `DATE JOINED`, `EMERGENCY CONTACT`) 
    values 
    (old.TITLE, old.NAME, old.`NAME OF SPOUSE`, old.`LEVEL OF EDUCATION`, old.`ADDRESS`, old.`PHONE NUMBER`,old.`OCCUPATION`, old.`DATE JOINED`, old.`EMERGENCY CONTACT`); 
END ; $$
delimiter ;
```

Make sure to backtick the column names when there is a space in between or in case using a reserve keyword.